# Fancybox works locally but not when uploaded to server

Tags: fancybox

Hi im hoping you guys can help me, I put together a fancybox gallery which works beautifully locally but when I uploaded it to server only 2 images work when clicked..Im at a loss as to why the others wont load, all images are in the same folder and paths are the same.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you link us to the broken gallery? And have you checked the "Network" tab in your browser debug tools to look for errors?

Comment: @Alex P http://c00173649.candept.com/BredaMaloneWebsite/Gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

By using the browser debug tools, we can see that your server's returning "404 not found" errors for all the images. It looks like your image paths are `img\thumb3.jpg`; web servers use forward slashes as a path separator. If you change your gallery so the images are `img/thumb3.jpg`, it should all work fine.

The reason this works locally but not when uploaded is because you're working on Windows, and your web server probably isn't. :)

Comment: Thanks Alex, problem still persisting unfortunately. very odd that it is finding two of the images but none of the rest

Comment: If I look at the source of your page, it's still making requests for the images with backslashes in the paths. Have you uploaded the latest version of your gallery?

Comment: I just noticed that myself! something going on with the server, it is not refreshing for some reason

Comment: Solved the problem..I used the full path for the larger images so instead of img/Image3.jpg I used href="http://c00173649.candept.com/BredaMaloneWebsite/img/Image3.jpg"